# facebook synchronous request using getSession

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my head

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var pic = 0;
    FB.init({appId: '135570939849404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    session = FB.getSession();
        if (session) {
                pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + session.uid + "/picture";  
        } 
});
</script>
```

and the following code in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                    document.write("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">");
                            </script>
```

Why is it that in the console it always gives me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pic is not defined
```

I have changed var pic to just pic, to make it global... however, still the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont Do it in the body tag. Instead Do it like this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var pic = 0;
    FB.init({appId: '135570939849404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    session = FB.getSession();
        if (session) {
                pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + session.uid + "/picture";  
        } 
        document.write("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">");
});
</script>
```

Comment: well then where will this <img src be located at?

Comment: if you want to write to a specific place, then again u can use jquery.
$("#id_holder").html("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">")
you can read about html, append and prepend functions of jquery. :)